# How can change language keyboard layout in Windows (c++)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, keyboard

I need change keyboard language.
with this code i can change the language if in focus app:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   //0409 - Ingles, 0c0a - Espanhol, 0416 - Portugues
   char *str = "0c0a";//argv[1];
   int i;

    if(EOF != sscanf(str, "%x", &i))
   {
      SendMessage(GetActiveWindow(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, 0, i);
   }
   system("PAUSE");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but i need change the system keyboard language definitely, after app is close or
if focus not set in app.

any can help me?

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Imagine if another app could do the same thing - who'd win? It is not your application that controls the language of the system, it's the user.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9669352/588306) posted less than 24 hours before yours

Comment: I'm not even sure that a "system keyboard language" exists; it looks like a per-process setting. BTW, `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` is a message from Windows (the OS) to inform a program that a user wanted to change the input language; it's not a supported way for programs to make requests to other programs.

Comment: What would be a valid reason for this behaviour? A program that changes system settings (and probably won't undo this, especially when it crashes) will be removed and banned from my PC immediately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **really** need to change user's keyboard layout you can use following functions:
[GetKeyboardLayoutName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LoadKeyboardLayout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Nope - "only affects the layout for the current process", i.e. not the "system keyboard language" from the question.

Comment: Sorry, I did miss the **system** word! I guess the only way is by registry (http://www.easydesksoftware.com/keyboard.htm).

Comment: But programs like Punto Switcher are doing it somehow in realtime. No reboot required .

Comment: @BogdanMart this answer is REALLY old. Starting with Windows 8 you can use `LoadKeyboardLayout()` to load and activate an input locale for the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

The next command changes the system keyboard layout to English:

```cpp
PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, 1, 0x04090409);
```

to Russian:

```cpp
PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, 1, 0x04190419);
```

I use it in my games in Qt and OpenGL ES 2.0 to set a keyboard layout to English. Because I need to detect WASD to control a player:

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif

OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow()
{
    setTitle("OpenGL ES 2.0, Qt6, C++");
    resize(350, 350);

#ifdef _WIN32
    PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, 1, 0x04090409);
#endif

    QSurfaceFormat surfaceFormat;
    surfaceFormat.setSwapInterval(1);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(frameSwapped()), this, SLOT(update()));
    setFormat(surfaceFormat);
}
```